# How to Query two XML files simultaneously in Java?

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, android-xml

In my scenario, I have two XML files and I wanna query these files simultaneously.

File 1, publishers.xml

```
<publishers>
    <publisher pubid="1" name="ABC" />
    <publisher pubid="2" name="RST" />
    <publisher pubid="3" name="XYZ" />
</publishers>
```

File 2, books.xml

```
<books>
    <book bkid="1" pubid="1" name="introduction to A" />
    <book bkid="2" pubid="3" name="introduction to B" />
    <book bkid="3" pubid="3" name="introduction to C" />
    <book bkid="4" pubid="2" name="introduction to D" />
</books>
```

QUESTION:

- Is there any XML Query thing available in Java/Android (similar to LINQ)?
- **IN JAVA**, how can I do this? (I want to query from two XML files simultaneously)

  `SELECT book FROM books.xml 
  JOIN publishers.xml ON publishers.pubid = books.pubid 
  AND bkid = "2"`

Let me explain in "plain" English :), the node `<book>` is selected from books.xml where the attribute `bkid=2` and at the same time `<publisher>` from the publishers.xml file where `publishers.pubid=books.pubid`.

DESIRED OUTPUT (processed):

```
Book ID: 2
Book Name: introduction to B
Publisher: XYZ
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can use Xpath to query xml, see : http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html

Comment: Thankx Anis! All the examples I have seen on the web are dealing with one xml file. And in my case, I need to read two xml files, conditionally.

Comment: is it too difficult question? I tried my best to explain the scenario. :)

Comment: Looking at the response this question receives and very little material and discussion on this topic, I am thinking is there anything wrong with this approach? Are people not using two XML files? If they are, how?

Answer (score 0):

Is this common?  no it is not, but sometimes necessary.  I would use Xquery as described in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484192/xquery-multiple-xml-files).  Of course if you could merge the files it would simplify your problem.

-- Edit --

Since Xquery doesn't seem to have very solid support on Android I would look at a different option:

1. Merge the files together:  You could pull both of the streams down, concat them inside of a new parent node `<root> xml files concat here </root>` then convert this string into a dom document and use xpath to parse it.

Comment: I read through tutorials and APIs and in the end I noticed it is not available on Android.

Comment: Thank Justin for the link, I have gone through that link quite thoroughly. I can't download the jar files listed on this page (timeout error). There's no support available, nothing is happening around this library.. don't know if it is worth taking the risk and download the sources. No one seems to talk about it on Stackoverflow either.

Comment: That's to bad, it looks like it was someones senior project but it had potential.  see my edit for another possible solution.  The data your using sounds fairly static, have you considered just pulling it down and caching it in sqlite so that you can easily query it any way you want?